# Need to set a FAILSAFE in an if else loop

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sketch

This works but I would like to have a timed failsafe...

If the `FLOAT_PIN` goes `LOW` for more than 3 seconds, it will turn `SOLENOID_PIN` to `LOW`.

I can't figure out how to incorporate it into my loop. I tried `delay()` and started playing with `millis()` but all I keep finding is LED blinking samples...

I'm not very good with C++ - still learning.

```cpp
const int FLOAT_PIN = 8; // Pin connected to FLOAT switch
const int SOLENOID_PIN = A0; // SOLENOID pin - active-high

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Since the other end of the FLOAT switch is connected to ground, we need
  // to pull-up the FLOAT switch pin internally.
  pinMode(FLOAT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(SOLENOID_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int floatswitch = digitalRead(FLOAT_PIN); // Read the state of the float switch

  if (floatswitch == HIGH) {
    // If the pin reads high, water is OFF.
    Serial.println("Switch closed");
    digitalWrite(SOLENOID_PIN, HIGH); // Turn the SOLENOID on
  } else {
    digitalWrite(SOLENOID_PIN, LOW); // Turn the SOLENOID off
  }
}
```

Comment: use a flag `floatFlag`.... `if floatSwitch == high and floatFlag == false`   `(floatFlag = true;`  `tim = currentTime;)` ...... `if floatSwitch == low` `(floatFlag == false)` ....... `if floatFlag == true and currentTime == tim +3 seconds` `(turn on valve)`

Comment: Also asked at: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=519688 If you're going to do that then please be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases when thinking in terms of a [finite state
machine](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/the-finite-state-machine/) makes the programming quite straightforward. Here I would
use three states:

- In the `OFF` state, the switch is `LOW` and the solenoid is off
- in the `ON` state, the switch is `HIGH` and the solenoid is on
- in the `DELAYING` state, the switch is `LOW`, but the program is
  keeping the switch `HIGH` for three seconds.

The possible transitions are:

- `OFF` → `ON` when the switch goes `HIGH`
- `ON` → `DELAYING` when the switch goes `LOW`
- `DELAYING` → `OFF` after three second in this state
- `DELAYING` → `ON` when the switch goes `HIGH`.

The last transition is meant to ensure that `LOW` states of the switch
that last less than three seconds do not turn the solenoid off.

And here is a tentative implementation. Keep your constants and your
`setup()`, and replace your `loop()` with this:

```
const uint32_t DELAY_TIME = 3000;  // time to deay the -> off transition

void loop() {
    static enum {OFF, ON, DELAYING} state;
    static uint32_t start_delay;
    int floatswitch = digitalRead(FLOAT_PIN);

    switch (state) {
        case OFF:
            if (floatswitch == HIGH) {
                Serial.println("Switch closed");
                digitalWrite(SOLENOID_PIN, HIGH); // Turn the SOLENOID on
                state = ON;
            }
            break;
        case ON:
            if (floatswitch == LOW) {
                start_delay = millis();
                state = DELAYING;
            }
            break;
        case DELAYING:
            if (floatswitch == HIGH) {
                state = ON;
            }
            else if (millis() - start_delay >= DELAY_TIME) {
                digitalWrite(SOLENOID_PIN, LOW); // Turn the SOLENOID off
                state = OFF;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: think its backwards. Worked but backwards, it's preventing it from turning off for 3 seconds, rather then turning off if its on for more then 3 seconds.

Comment: no matter what I do it works one way but not the other... not sure what i did wrong.

Comment: @MikeS: I can't understand your comment “it's preventing it from turning off for 3 seconds, rather then turning off if its on for more then 3 seconds”. I wrote this answer to match your question as written. If this is not the behavior you expect, please, edit your question with a more explicit description of your expectations.

Comment: your example works, but not as intended. Float goes low, turn on solenoid, Float goes high, turns off solenoid but delays 3 seconds once Float is high. The logic about is right, not sure if your states are written correctly. Can it be written outside the loop that Solenoid can only be high for X seconds (no matter the output of the FLOAT?)

Comment: @MikeS: This works exactly as intended – as **I** intended it to work based on my understanding of your question. I assume you didn't read my last comment, so let me repeat: **please, update your question and add an explicit and clear description of the behaviour you expect.**